# I am trying to find a way to act on characters in an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

I am very new to coding and Python. I am trying to change characters in string elements of an array conditional on their adjacency to another character.

These characters are grouped into arrays based on shared sound qualities (it's a linguistics matter). So what I am trying to do is iterate a sound change through an array of strings.

Here is the gist of things:

```
W = ["w","u"]
Ḱ = ["ḱ","ǵ","ǵʰ"]
K = ["k","g","gʰ"]

for i in df["word"]:
  for j in i:
    if j == Ḱ and (i[j+1] == W or i[j-1] == W):
      i=i.replace(Ḱ, K, regex=True)
  df["word"] == df["word"]
```

I was expecting something like ǵwe to become gwe or uǵʰi to become ugʰi, but nothing changes. It is horridly annoying

Comment: What do you expect `df["word"] == df["word"]` to do?

Comment: Furthermore, you iterating through each character in the word which is assigned to variable `j`. `i[j+1]` is just going to throw an error since a character in a word plus 1 doesn't work. It never gets the opportunity to throw an error though because `j == Ḱ` doesn't make sense.  A single character of a word will never be equal to a list. I think some very basic debugging steps are in order.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all the letters from a list to the corresponding letters in another list, you will need to structure your code differently.

From what I understood of your problem something like this will work:

```
old_words = ['ǵwe', 'uǵʰi'] # init
new_words = []

for word  in old_words:
    for i, w in enumerate(Ḱ):
        word = word.replace(w, K[i]) # replace for each word in Ḱ with corresponding word in K
    new_words.append(word)
new_words
```

Output:

```
['gwe', 'ugʰi']
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to stay as true to your original intended logic as possible, a rewrite fixing the numerous issues would look like:

```
W = ["w","u"]
Ḱ = ["ḱ","ǵ","ǵʰ"]
K = ["k","g","gʰ"]

i='ǵwe'

for idx, j in enumerate(word):
    prev_char = word[idx - 1] if idx > 0  else None
    next_char = word[idx + 1] if idx < len(i)-1 else None
    if (j in Ḱ) and bool(set(W) & {prev_char, next_char}):
        word[idx]=K[Ḱ.index(j)]
        
print(''.join(word))
```

This solves for a single word held in variable `i`. A few notable changes:

1. In order to refer to list elements by their index, you will need to `enumerate()` list/string `i`/`word`. This will return both an index as well as the character.
2. To see if an item is IN a list, you use the `IN` operator, not `==`.
3. `str.replace()` method takes two string arguments, not two lists; furthemore, it's dangerous since if you have more than one instance of a character that is due for replacement, it will change all of them even if they aren't next to a `W`.
4. The `bool()` condition/test is a nice little trick to see if two lists contain at least one element in common. Since we are wanting to see if the prev/next character is in the list `W`, it serves as a quick test without needing the `or`.

As for working with a dataframe, do not iterate. Instead you want to use `apply()` after tossing the above code into a function.

```
import pandas as pd

def replace_chars(i):
    W = ["w","u"]
    Ḱ = ["ḱ","ǵ","ǵʰ"]
    K = ["k","g","gʰ"]

    word = list(i)
    for idx, j in enumerate(word):
        prev_char = word[idx - 1] if idx > 0  else None
        next_char = word[idx + 1] if idx < len(i)-1 else None
        if (j in Ḱ) and bool(set(W) & {prev_char, next_char}):
            word[idx]=K[Ḱ.index(j)]        
            
    return ''.join(word)

df = pd.DataFrame({"word":['ǵwe', 'uǵʰi', 'test2']})            
df["word2"] = df["word"].apply(lambda x: replace_chars(x))
display(df)
```

It may make sense to use a dictionary for your "k" sounds swapping which should help simplify your code and gives you a path forward for adding more sounds to swap (a nested dictionary structure would be the next logical step, for instance). This would look something like:

```
def replace_chars(i):
    W = ["w","u"]   
    k_sounds = {"ḱ":"k","ǵ":"g","ǵʰ":"gʰ"}

    word = list(i)
    for idx, j in enumerate(word):
        prev_char = word[idx - 1] if idx > 0 else None
        next_char = word[idx + 1] if idx < len(word)-1 else None
        if j in k_sounds.keys() and bool(set(W) & {prev_char, next_char}):
            word[idx]=k_sounds[j]           
    return ''.join(word)
```

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't sure how to respond until now. Worked very flexibly.